# Aligning text layers in Android

Tags: text, typography, alignment, android

**The situation -**
I need to hand over designs to my devs. I have created some spacing tokens, that I am using in Sketch(the design software). These tokens are based on baseline alignment of the text layer and I'm using them to give vertical spacing between a heading and body. Now sketch renders a text box around the text layer, based on the line height. When I am viewing this design in Abstract(version control/dev handoff tool), it's giving a different text box rendering. The same problem is when I view the text box in zeplin(another dev handoff tool). These values are showing as random numbers(not following the 8pt grid, that I have based my tokens on).

**The problem -**
Android has no concept of baseline alignment. What spacing reference do I use in order to make sure that my designs are developed with the exact same spacing as in my design file. Also, is there a way to implement baseline alignment in Android?

Comment: about implementing baseline alignment in Android: that'd be off-topic here, better ask on [so]